# Can I build a shared library for Android (*.so) in Embarcadero C++Builder?

Tags: android, c++, shared-libraries, cross-platform, c++builder

I am trying to create a shared library, using Embarcadero's C++Builder and RAD Studio 10.2. I created a C++Builder "Dynamic Linked Library" project. When I specify the target platforms to build for, the only options are 32-bit Windows, 64-bit Windows, and OS X. I need to be able to build the library for the Android (Linux) platform as well. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time, RADStudio (including Delphi and C++Builder) **does not** support the *creation* of custom `.so` libraries for Android (only *consuming* them). Per the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/API_(*.bpl,_*.dylib,_*.so)), `.so` files can be created for Linux (and `.dylib` files for OSX/iOS) by creating a Delphi-style Package instead of a Dynamic-Link Library.

RADStudio-created Android apps are compiled as `.so` files (because they are based on the NDK, so the real app is just a small Java stub class that loads and executes the `.so` at runtime), but that is the extent of Embarcadero's `.so` generation on Android.  Compiling custom `.so` libraries for Android is simply not supported yet.

Comment: Hm... weird... the documentation does not mention the Android platform...

Comment: @Migrate2Lazarusseemyprofile yes, because creating custom packages for Android is (still) not supported at this time.

Comment: Yes. I mean, I expected them to lest all OSs and say something like "Android: not supported". Do you think (just a guesstimate) that feature will be available soon?

Comment: @Migrate2Lazarusseemyprofile "*Do you think (just a guesstimate) that feature will be available soon?*" - no, I do not.